# Cannot remove IE 8 icon from desktop

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 32-bit and am trying to remove the Internet Explorer 8 icon from my desktop as I don't use it.

I've tried:

- Turning IE 8 off from the Control Panel but the stubborn icon still remains.
- Right-clicking on the icon and selecting Delete but it takes me to the Internet Properties window.
- Dragging the icon to the Recycle Bin but it still remains.

I'm running avast! Antivirus so I don't think it's a virus. What can I do to get rid of this icon?

Comment: dragging it to the trash worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to remove the icon. Locate the following key in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace
```

Search in it, find the "Internet Explorer" name and delete it. After refreshing the desktop, the icon is gone.

Answer (score 2):

[How to remove the Internet Explorer (IE) icon from the desktop in Windows 7 using the Group Policy editor](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/hide-the-internet-explorer-icon-on-the-desktop/)